# HTML layout - making dimensions of cells in separate tables match

Tags: html, css, layout, datatables, html-table

### Background

I'm trying to clone parts of a table and overlay the clones on top of the original table in order to create headers that are fixed on the page when scrolling.  I'm using a jQuery plugin: a modified version of [datatables](http://datatables.net/) [FixedHeader](http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/) to do this.  I tried [FixedColumns](http://datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/) but it doesn't work the way I want.

I have the above working except that the cloned tables don't line up properly with the source table.  e.g. the top header has cells that are narrower than the cells in the real table.

I've tried setting the widths of the cells like the original FixedHeader code does, but this does not seem to have any effect.  Also, if manually set the widths in Firebug's Layout tab it updates the style="width: blah" in the element in the HTML view, but does not actually change the width of the cells.

### Question

How do I set the widths of cells in a second table to match the widths of the cells in the original table so that they line up when I position the second table on top of the first table.

For a simpler version of the above, consider the following code.  Even though I have explicitly set the widths of the first two `th` elements in both tables, the second table's cells are too narrow.  I don't want to specify the widths of the cells in the original table.  I only want to set the widths of the cells in the second table to match the first.  How do I do this?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Layout</title>
<style type="text/css">
td, th {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 0px 1px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
th {
    font-weight: normal;
}
th.colhead {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
th.reference {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 100%;
}
th.rowhead {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
th.cathead {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
tr {
    height: 31px;
}
tr.even {
    background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="source">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="colhead" style="width:156px">Test Name</th>
          <th class="colhead" style="width:102px">Reference Range</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="rowhead">This is the test</th>
          <th class="rowhead">123 - 456</th>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="thead_clone">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="colhead" style="width:156px">Test Name</th>
          <th class="colhead" style="width:102px">Reference Range</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
          <th class="colhead">26-07-2011 15:58</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I've discovered that for the above code, setting the width of the second `table` to the same as the first `table` fixes the issue, but in my real code, the cells are still the wrong width.  How do I figure out where the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: I ran into the same issue few months ago, but couldn't find any easy solution...

Comment: Would using a jQuery plugin be an option? http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/floatHeader

Comment: And more broadly than the question about jQuery plugins, would using JavaScript be ok? I don't think there's a solution to this without JS.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using the datatables.net jQuery plugin with the FixedHeader "extra" (http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/) which I have modified to freeze 2 columns on the left instead of just 1, and to freeze the top left cells as well.

Comment: js/jquery, or not (I have tested a lot of these solutions), it sucks if you want pixel precision. Columns width will change depending on cells content, even if you use a fixed width for every columns.

Comment: @powerbuoy I am already using datatables.net FixedHeader to do this, because I need the `thead` and also the left column(s) to be fixed.  Unfortunately I needed to modify it because I need two left columns fixed and not just one.  Also the top left cells need to be fixed.

Comment: @soju OK, but the contents are not going to change once the table has been created.  And at that point I can query the widths/heights of everything and in theory set the widths/heights of the corresponding elements in the second table, but the browser seems to ignore them sometimes :(

Answer (score 0):

In your example you set two columns in the first table at an exact width. This results in the first two columns of your second table getting 'too narrow' because their width is relative instead of absolute, so the browser figures how wide they should be comparing to the other columns.

Your choice is simple: set both of the table columns with an exact width or both of them without. Otherwise, there will always be differences. If you don't (for both) the width of the header columns also depends on the width of the cells in the rows below them, which depends on what's in them. This means either you don't use exact width and you have to make the two tables exactly identical in terms of content (so two whole tables), or you specify exact column widths for both, in which case you can make do with only the header row for the second table.

If I would have to take care of this, I'd say generate one table and use jQuery or MooTools to make the duplicate header columns. So then you query the DOM, copy, paste, set width.

Comment: Thanks, as I said towards the end of my question I do not want to specify the exact widths of the cells in the first table.  I do want to query the dom and set the widths of the cells in the second table so that they match the first table.  However, when I try this, either by manually editing the widths using Firebug, or by using Javascript (in my hacked version of http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/) it does not actually change the widths of the cells in the second table.

Comment: Could you set up a jsfiddle to illustrate this better? Because the html + css does not show this, really. I've been doing some fancy positioning/cloning stuff with MooTools and had some differences in pixels, but I could always work them out as they are a result of border, padding etc. - the css styling, generally.

Comment: yes js fiddle it, it should change the widths (did you try with table-layout set to fixed ?). kasimir can you show us your solution ? because mine (modified version of fixed header from drupal core) is ok, but with more/less pixels depending on browser...

Comment: I've never used jsfiddle before.  Gave it a try, but could not get it working yet.  Not sure if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/VLHm8/

Comment: There's loads and loads of references to local files, so you should resolve these first to get the jsfiddle to work (hopefully) and be of some use to determine what the real issue is.

Comment: @kasimir unless I'm missing something the only references to local files are in the CSS and they should not have any effect.  I'll try to clean that up, though, and get it working in jsfiddle.

Comment: According to my developer console (in Safari) there are seven missing javascript files (404 errors). You might've put al that stuff in the javascript window in jsfiddle, but I can't really tell.

Comment: OK, I see now.  It seems it hadn't saved the latest version of the HTML with those references removed.  I've fixed that and got it mostly working now, although the table seems messed up for some reason.  e.g. some rows re longer than others, which does not happen with the real files.  http://jsfiddle.net/VLHm8/4/

Comment: What I can tell, is the headers you can see (top) do not align with the body rows below, because they are not in the same table and there are al kinds of cells with exacts widths etc. I think the FixedHeader stuff is working against you here. So if you really want this to work, I guess you have to program something yourself. Or simplify/drop some demands and get FixedHeader working properly.